# multiply records by relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This are my relations:

```
class House
 has_many: appartments
end

class Appartments
 belongs_to: house
end

class Region
 has_many: houses
end
```

Controller:

```
@country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
@regions = @country.regions
@house = House.find(params[:id])
```

View

On the house page i have a tab where i want to show appartments which belong to the house.

This is my loop:

```
- @regions.each do |region|
  - region.houses.each do |house|
    - @house.appartments.each do |appartment|
      %section
        .row
          .span5
            %h2 #{link_to appartment.name, country_region_appartment_path(@country, region, appartment)}
            %p
```

i created this loop because i need the region values for the link. It works..i get the appartments wich belong to the house...but i multiplies the records/output.

What a i doing wrong?

Thanks..remco

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem/what you expect please?

Comment: i want to show the appartments which belong to the house....it works but it shows the appartments multiply times

Comment: Try with `appartments = @regions.flat_map(&:houses).flat_map(&:appartments).uniq` and then loop on it with a `.each`

Comment: Hey Remco, if this is, or possibly will be, a collaborative effort - you should never have something as big as a model be misspelled. Your `Appartment` model should actually be `Apartment`.  Your choice though.

Answer (score 0):

The `@house` has no relation to the `region.houses` in your view. You loop through all the houses from one region, but then you use the same variable populated on your controller `@house`.
Also i believe there are some associations missing:

```
class Region
  has_many: houses
  belongs_to :country
end

class House
  has_many :appartments
  belongs_to :region
end

class Appartment
  belongs_to :house
end
```

On your controller you just need to query for the regions:

```
@country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
@regions = @country.regions
```

And in your view you should remove the `@` from house, as it references only one predefined house:

```
- @regions.each do |region|
  - region.houses.each do |house|
    - house.appartments.each do |appartment|
```

This is a primitive way of doing it, as it would fire many queries on demand. So if you have many records, you may have a look at eager loading your data using something like `include` and `join` from `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: i tried that but then i get all the appartments from the region and not from the house

Comment: Murifo...thanks...i tried your idea but then i get all the apartments from the region...